# Minimum Size of dominating set of n*n table

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What is the minimum size of [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) of $N*N$ table graph?
$N*N$ table graph definition: Consider each cell of table a vertex and connect vertex v and vertex u when cell v and cell u is adjacent in table.
[image: The graph of the 4*4 table]

Comment: This is [A104519](https://oeis.org/A104519). Look that up.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5206 answer this. Unfortunatley, stackexchange seems to require answers with at least 30 characters, which is the reason for this second sentence.